# TinyMCE Doesn't Fit in Page When Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, tinymce

I've created a "compose note" button that when clicked displays an initially hidden div that contains a form with a TinyMCE textarea.

The problem I'm having is that, when displayed, the TinyMCE textarea is way too wide and doesn't fit in the rest of the page. It just protrudes out with everything else past the page being white. I don't have the same problem with my other TinyMCE textareas where the width adjusts as I adjust the width of my browser.

My guess is that it must be a CSS problem but I've been fiddling around with the CSS with no success.

Please find my JQuery code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#compose-button').click(
    function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "Compose note") {
            $(this).val("Cancel note");
            $('#compose').css({'display' : 'block'});
            $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({  
               script_url : 'jscripts/tinymce_3.4.1_jquery/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',  
               theme : "advanced",
               plugins: "save, table, tinyautosave, imagemanager, spellchecker, autoresize",
               theme_advanced_buttons1_add_before : "tinyautosave, code, separator, delete_table",
               theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,fontsizeselect,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,code,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,insertimage,spellchecker",
               theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
               theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
               theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
               theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left"     
            });  
        }
        else {
            $(this).val("Compose note");
            $('#compose').css({'display' : 'none'});
        }
    });
});
```

Please find my CSS below:

```
html, body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 780px;
    min-height: 500px;
    }
div#compose{display: none;}
#compose ul{list-style: none; margin-left: 10px;}
#compose li{padding: 3px;}
#compose label {width: 30px; padding-right: 30px; float: left;}
#compose input, #compose select {color:black; width: 400px; text-align: left;}
```

Please find my HTML below:

```
<div id="compose">
    <!--Form-->
    <form action="<?php htmlout($action); ?>" method="post" id="compose-form">
    <ul>
        <!--Name-->    
        <li><label for="note_name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="note_name" id="note_name" value=""/></li>

        <!--Note Type-->
        <li>
            <label for="note_type">Type:</label>
            <select name="note_type" id="note_type">
                <option value="">Select one:</option>
                //PHP stuff
                </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </li>

        <!--Tags-->
        <li><label for="tag">Tags:</label><input type="text" name="tag" id="tag_search"></li>

        <!--Text-->      
        <li><label for="note_text">Notes:</label><textarea class="tinymce" name="note_text" id="note_text"><?php htmlout($note_text); ?></textarea></li>

        <!--ID-->    
        <li><input type="hidden" name="note_id" value="<?php htmlout($note_id); ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="<?php htmlout($button); ?>"/></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you place your example somewhere on a webpage, so that we could have a closer look?

Comment: For an example, please check out http://ksindi.com/example/example.php

To see example, first click "compose note" button. Then minimize screen to about 500px wide. If you go to the right of the page then, you will see TinyMCE protruding past the light blue div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the autoresize plugin. Remove it. If you want to keep it, then also use `theme_advanced_resizing : true` to resize it to whatever you want.

autoresize also makes initialization much slower.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to put the tinymce buttons (UI objects) into more than one row.
This won't solve the underliing problem, but it could be that your tinymce will fit in in most cases.

Comment: I agree with Thariama, the main problem is the toolbar. TinyMCE uses the "width" config item to ensure it's at least that size hoever TinyMCE expands to the maximum width of the toolbar to ensure all items are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the width and height properties in the tinymce definition?

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({

           width: '100px',
           height: '100px',

           script_url : 'jscripts/tinymce_3.4.1_jquery/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',  
           theme : "advanced",
           plugins: "save, table, tinyautosave, imagemanager, spellchecker, autoresize",
           theme_advanced_buttons1_add_before : "tinyautosave, code, separator, delete_table",
           theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,fontsizeselect,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,code,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,insertimage,spellchecker",
           theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
           theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left"     
        });
```

Comment: Hi Cubic Digital Team. I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think Thariama might have a point. It looks like the width is being forced by all the buttons on your example

Comment: yes, this is correct - the buttons define (indirectly) the minimum width